# How do I make one of the primary keys in a primary composite key autogenerate?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to autogenerate one of the primary keys in a primary key pair in Android room, but I cannot find a way to do this ("@PrimaryKey(autogenerate=true))"  only works with a non-composite primary key. Any ideas on how I can solve this? Thanks!

Essentially the idea is that I have the following set of models:
Patient -> Injury -> BodyPart

I'd like to be able to incorporate patientId in all 3 models, but also have a connection between injury and x many body parts (injuryId).

Here is the database model I am trying to implement:

```
@Entity(tableName = "injury_table", indices = {@Index(value = "patientId")},
        primaryKeys = {"injuryId","patientId"},
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Patient.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "patientId",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class Injury {

    //@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "injuryId")
    public long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "patientId")
    public long patientId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "injuryName")
    public String name;

    public int severity;

    ...
```

Comment: If injuryId is autogenerated then it is automatically unique. Why would you need a composite primaryKey?

Comment: I'd like to be able to get a listing of body parts by patientId, but I would also like to be able to list all body parts effected by injury. (in an efficient manner)

Comment: Sounds like you mean an [index](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#indices-uniqueness), not a primary key